# Coherence vs. Magnitude Squared Coherence

Tags: power-spectral-density, magnitude, coherence

currently I am writing my masther thesis. The theory part is about the turbulent wind field generation, where the coherence (not magnitude squared) is used:

$$\text{coh}(f) = \frac{|P_{xy}|}{\sqrt{P_{xx} P_{yy}}}$$

I am wondering what is the general advantage of using the magnitude squared coherence instead:

$$\text{coh}^2(f) = \frac{|P_{xy}|^2}{P_{xx} P_{yy}}$$

I think this relationship is similar to that of the correlation coefficient $R$ and coefficient of determination $R^2$. I tried to google the difference regarding the coherence, but unfortunately I don't find any (good) explanations.

Hopefully someone can help me. Thanks in advance!

Apollo3zehn

Answer (score 1):

Your analogy between the coherence function and the correlation coefficient is correct.  (The slight difference is that $-1 \leq R \leq 1$, whereas $0 \leq \operatorname{coh}(f) \leq 1$ in your definition, likely because it is possible for $P_{xy}$ to be complex-valued.

Intuitively, the cross spectral density (CSD) $P_{xy}$ can be thought of as a [measure of the correlation of the spectra of the individual signals at each frequency](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/what-is-cross-spectral-density-csd). Normalizing the CSD by the square root of the product of the individual PSDs creates something akin to a correlation coeffcient, like the $R$ you pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the calculation of the magnitude squared coherence is faster for computers (multiplication is faster than square root calculations). And that's pretty much it. :P

Answer (score 0):

I've also been a bit befuddled by which of these I should use. There is no clear standard, unfortunately. To make things worse, I've come across written work where it is unclear which is being used. I've lost a few days trying to decipher this.

Personally, I like magnitude squared coherence. The lack of a `sqrt` seems cleaner to me. If I were king of the world, I'd make everyone use $\mathrm{coh}^2$.

But---since I'm not ;)---you can use whichever you like. Just be sure to clearly document which one you are using and *how you're calculating it*. Many people don't realize that you have to do some ensemble averaging of $P$ *before* computing $\mathrm{coh}$ or $\mathrm{coh}^2$.

Answer (score 0):

it might also be that the magnitude-squared has no discontinuities whereas the magnitude has a discontinuity in its derivative at zero.  so the magnitude-square is easier to do calculus with.

it's like why the formula for fitting a line (or any polynomial or sum of basis functions) to data and using the mean-square error instead of the mean-absolute-value error.  minimizing the mean-square error, with respect to some parameter, is easy because you can take derivatives without worry that the derivative might not exist for some value.